# Get email from google user id(or vice versa)

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-oauth

I have a list of emails(gmail) and a list of google ids without any access/refresh tokens. Is it possible to figure out which google id belongs to which email?

Comment: List the messages thru [`Users.messages: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), from there you will be able to get the message `id` and `threadId`. Then you can proceed with getting the specific message by using the [`Users.messages: get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) providing the `userId` which has the value equal to your email address and the special value **`me`** can be use to indicate the authenticated user. The value `id` you have got from the `list` is required for this request.

Comment: What you want is not possible. If google allowed for that, it would make for a massive breach in security...